# sklearn predict() function too slow for line by line prediction

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a challenge which I am working on that simulates my server receiving real-time information such that I can only make predictions line by line. I am using random forest regressor - optimised for speed.

The problem is not with `predict()` function, but calling it line by line which creates alot of overhead.

Is there anything i can do to increase the run-time performance?
Or an alternative approach to achieve the same model accuracy whilst improving run-time?

Maybe another library in which the `predict()` function does not require such large overhead?

Tried different sklearn model, from complex to simple (linear regression) and the performance issue still exists.  Which shows the issue is with the overhead required with the predict function rather than the model itself.

I tried to predict on a sample dataset with 300k labels, and the pre-trained model predicts it within 4 seconds.

```
Class test(b):
    def predict(self, data, model):
        #form feature dataframe X using data 
        prediction = model.predict()
        return prediction[0]

    def run(self):
        model = pickle.load("model.pkl")
        streaming_data_row = #gets a row of data.  Dimensions 1x11 
        prediction = predict(streaming_data_row, model)
        self.submit(prediction) 
        #MUST EXECUTE self.submit() before next streaming_data_row can be received.
```

Comment: [This sklearn page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_prediction_latency.html) seems to indicate that random forest is the slowest-performing predictor when doing individual (atomic) predictions (out of the ones they benchmarked). Have you tried other models and not gotten the results you want? And are you holding the model in memory, or are you including something like unpickling in the prediction time?

Comment: Please show us your code and details about your data dimension

Comment: G. Anderson.

It is a pre-trained model which I am deploying on the server.
I unpickle it once and keep in memory to reduce time wasted.

I tried simple linear regression, but run time for that is same as random forest - meaning its not the predict() function itself but rather calling it constantly within a loop (500k times) is what is causing the delays.

Regarding the data - its-pretrained on 3 million data points.  And predicting one row at a time with 11 columns.

Comment: Maybe it is just the slow speed of Python. Can you compare the performance of the model with just adding all 11 Features? What’s the difference?

Comment: sample code added.

Comment: Dieshe, I am using all 11 features.  The performance is not bottlenecked by the number of features but rather the overhead created by calling predict(), row by row.

Comment: If prediction from any model is taking too long, then you might need to look into doing multiple predictions in parallel via some adjustments to your architecture. If even the most basic linear regression was too slow, it's unlikely that you'll be able to improve much on that. Are you expecting to see your actual use case require throughput of 500k predictions per second (or per whatever-time-frame)? Or are you just trying to see the maximum?

Comment: G. Anderson.
I am requiring throughput of 500k predictions per X timeframe - Yes.
Also I cannot make parallel predictions since I get the data row by row (which is a timeseries)

Comment: What do you mean by slow? What performance numbers are you getting?